# why log message duplicated in father process?

Tags: python, logging

I have created new process like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import logging.handlers
import time

def new_log(file_name, level):
    log = logging.getLogger()
    h = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(file_name, maxBytes=10485760)
    h.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s'))
    log.addHandler(h)

    log_level = logging.DEBUG
    if level == 'debug':
        log_level = logging.DEBUG
    elif level == 'info':
        log_level = logging.INFO
    elif level == 'warn':
        log_level = logging.WARN
    elif level == 'error':
        log_level = logging.ERROR
    elif level == 'critical':
        log_level = logging.CRITICAL

    log.setLevel(log_level)
    return log

def func():
    child_logger = new_log('child', 'debug')
    for i in range(0, 10):
        child_logger.debug('child process running on %d' % i)
        time.sleep(1)

def father():
    father_logger = new_log('father', 'debug')
    father_logger.debug('this is father process')
    proc = Process(target = func, args = ())
    proc.start()

father()
```

the two different logger will log different messages, but when `child_logger` log some message, the `father_logger` still log the same message, why this happend? how to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

getLogger() returns the root logger. This means each time new_logger() is called it is adding a new handler to the root logger and setting the root loggers level.

Get a new logger on each call with this and set it's level:

```
log = logging.getLogger(file_name)
h = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(file_name, maxBytes=10485760)
h.setLevel(level)
```

Note: Use capitalised strings for level as logger accepts them i.e 'DEBUG' will work without converting it to logging.DEBUG